# MariaDB to MySQL migration using AWS DMS

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, migration, aws-aurora

I have a master-slave mariadb 10.3.29 running on AWS EC2 and needs to be migrated to AWS Aurora MySQL using DMS. In order to do that i need to change the binlog_format to ROW(both master and slave) and as per mariadb documentation its a dynamic parameter, which i assume "NO" reboot is required. Is that a correct assumption and any other FLUSH commands i need to run?

I also tried to find the parameter "binlog_format" in this config file "50-server.cnf" and could not find. However running `"SHOW VARIABLES like '%binlog_format%';"` shows the binlog_format is MIXED.

So wondering if binlog_format is not explicitly specified in the .cnf file, by default mariaDB takes MIXED and if i have to change it to ROW, it needs be added under "[mysqld]" in the above config file?

Answer (score 0):

[binlog_format](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#binlog_format) is a dynamic system, so it will take effect on the next statement if set in a session.

If it is set globally (this is what you want), the next connections will adopt the new binlog_format.

Nothing else is required to change the `binlog_format`.